# What are all the friendly and enemy ultimate sounds?

Tags: overwatch

When ultimates are used in Overwatch, a unique voice line sound effect is played, and it sounds different depending on which team used the ability. Does anyone have a list of what the two voice lines are for each character? Also some enemy voice lines seem to be much harder to hear (Widowmaker, Symmetra), so an indication of the relative volume would be great as well.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Format**

- Quote as enemy
- Quote as ally

**Ana**

- Warīhum quwitak!
- Nano Boost administered.
- You're powered up, get in there. (self and target)

**Bastion**

- Whe-whe-whe-wheee-whee-wheee (uses his beeps to play the [charge fanfare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_(fanfare)))
- (None)

**D.Va**

- Nerf this!
- Activating self-destruct sequence.

**Doomfist**

- Meteor Strike!
- Incoming!

**Genji**

- Ryūjin no ken wo kurae!/ Oni no ken wo kurae (Oni)
- The dragon becomes me!/ The demon becomes me (Oni)

**Hanzo**

- Ryuu ga waga teki wo kurau / Okami yo waga teki wo kurae! (Lone
  Wolf, Okami)
- Let the dragon consume you! / The wolf hunts for its prey! (Lone
  Wolf, Okami)

**Junkrat**

- Fire in the hole! / Get ready for a shock! (Dr. Junkenstein)
- Ladies and gentlemen, start your engines! / Ladies and Gentleman, my latest creation! (Dr. Junkenstein)

**Lúcio**

- Drop the beat!
- Oh, let's break it down!

**McCree**

- It's high noon./It's high tides (Lifeguard)
- Step right up.

**Mei**

- Dòng zhù! Bù xǔ zǒu!
- Freeze! Don't move!

**Mercy**

- Gemeinsam wir kämpfen!
- I will watch over you!/Heroes never die/Heroes never die... for a price(Imp, Devil)/Till Valhalla(valkyrie, Sigrun)/My servants never die(Witch

**Orisa**

- Cease your resistance!
- Team up for special attack.

**Pharah**

- Justice rains from above!
- Rocket barrage, incoming!

**Reaper**

- Die, die, die!
- Clearing the area.

**Reinardt**

- Hammer down!
- (None)

**Roadhog**

- Eat this!
- Laughs

**Soldier 76**

- I've got you in my sights.
- Tactical visor activated. / Tactical sunglasses activated. (Grillmaster: 76)

**Sombra**

- Apagando las luces!
- EMP activated!

**Symmetra**

*Teleporter*

- Your allies will say some variation of "The enemy has a teleporter!" when deployed, and will keep repeating those lines until the teleporter is destroyed. (She has no vocal line that you can hear, though a sound is made, you can listen to it [here](https://youtu.be/vSQaVF5kmdc?t=130))
- Teleporter online. I have opened the path/ Teleporter online. We move swiftly

*Shield Generator*

- Your allies will say some variation of "The enemy has a shield generator!" when deployed, and will keep repeating those lines until the shield generator is destroyed.
- Shield generator online. You are protected. / Shield generator online. Defense matrix established. / Shield matrix established.

**Tracer**

- Gotcha!(stuck to you) / Time's up! (bomb lands away from enemies)/
  Here you go! (bomb lands near an enemy)
- Right on target (enemy stuck) / Wait for it! (bomb lands in the
  ground)

**Torbjorn**

- Molten Core!!! / Merry Molten Core!!! (Santa Torbjorn)
- (None)

**Widowmaker**

- Personne n'échappe à mon regard.
- No one can hide from my sight./ No one can hide from the huntress (huntress,comtesse)

**Winston**

- Roars
- Roars

**Zarya**

- Ogon po gotovnosti!
- Fire at will!

**Zenyatta**

- Pass into the Iris.
- Experience tranquility. / Experience oblivion. (Cultist Zenyatta)

[source,](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4jx253/ult_sounds_enemy_vs_ally/)
 [other source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/5bgkp0/sombra_ingame_quotesvoicelines/)
**Note: ** Allied lines will be quieter than enemy lines.

Comment: It seems you read Symmetra's part wrong. She has no line when as an enemy, instead teammates will call out an enemy teleporter being online, with lines such as "They've got a teleporter!" or "Find that teleporter and destroy it!".

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer good catch. i fixed that now.

Comment: There *is* a sound effect though for enemies, just not a voice line

Comment: While there are lines for seeing and destroying a teleporter, there will also be a line whenever a teleporter is created, even if no one on the team has seen it.

Comment: It's also worth noting that except for Mercy, Symmetra, and Widowmaker, the enemy callout is the same as the self callout. Those three use the friendly callout for self.

Comment: Is the friendly and enemy bastion sound the same?

Comment: @Bonnici yes they are the same.

Comment: @Dragonrage could you also add Sombra's lines?

Comment: @DrFish added sombra

Comment: This is being treated as a community wiki answer but it's not one, so editing it can be awkward. It really should be made community wiki since new lines are always being added.

Comment: I thought Mercy and Junkrat is never an ally in junkenstein?

Answer (score 3):

Here are the voice lines for each character. First is the one you hear when an enemy uses it, followed by the one when an ally uses it, italicized (if they differ). With very few exceptions, the enemy-heard lines are much louder, to alert you.

**Bastion**: The ["charge" fanfare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_(fanfare)), in his trademark beeps.

**D.Va**: "Nerf this!" *"Activating self-destruct sequence!"*

**Genji**: "Ryūjin no ken wo kurae!" *"The dragon becomes me!"*

**Hanzo**: "Ryū ga waga teki wo kurau!" *"Let the dragon consume you!"*

When using his Lone Wolf or Okami skins, Hanzo's lines instead become "Okami yo waga teki wo kurae!" and *"The wolf hunts for its prey!"*

**Junkrat**: "Fire in the hole!" *"Ladies and gentlemen, start your engines!"*

**Lúcio**: "Oh, let's break it down!" *"Drop the beat!"*

**McCree**: "It's high noon!" *"Step right up."*

**Mei**: "Dòng zhù! Bù xǔ zǒu!" *"Freeze! Don't move!"*

**Mercy**: "Helden sterben nicht!" *"Heroes never die!"*

If using her Valkyrie or Sigurn skins, the allied line changes to *"'Till Valhalla!"*. If using the Imp or Devil skins, it becomes *"Heroes never die... for a price!"*

**Pharah**: "Justice rains from above!" *"Rocket barrage, incoming!"*

**Reaper**: "Die, die, die!" *"Clearing the area."*

**Reinhardt**: "Hammer down!"

**Roadhog**: "Eat this!" **laughter**

**Soldier: 76**: "I've got you in my sights!" *"Tactical visor activated!"*

**Symmetra**: Symmetra does not have an enemy-heard line. However, if your allies notice enemies returning to the battle rapidly, or find or destroy the teleporter pad, they will shout to notify you of its existence. Her ally-heard line is *"Teleporter online. I have opened the path."*

**Torbjörn**: "MOLTEN CORE!!"

**Tracer**: Depending on how the bomb lands, one of these pairs of lines will play:

(when stuck to an enemy) "Gotcha!" *"Right on target!"*

(when missing an enemy, but close) "Here you go!" *"Wait for it..."*

(when not landing near enemies) "Time's up!" *"Wait for it..."*

**Widowmaker**: "Personne n'échappe à mon regard." *"No one can hide from my sight!"*

Widowmaker's lines are reversed in volume from the norm -- her enemies will find it very difficult to pick out the line unless they are practically on top of her, while her allies will be made very aware that she has used her visor.

**Winston**: *roaring*

**Zarya**: "Огонь по готовности!" (roughly "Ogon po gotovnosti"*) *"Fire at will!"*

**Zenyatta**: "Pass into the Iris!" *"Experience tranquility."*

*According to a very dear friend of mine who studied abroad in Russia, this is actually incorrect; "Огонь" is the noun for an actual physical fire, not the verb for firing a weapon.

Comment: Indeed, "Огонь" by itself is noun in Russian, but in current phrase it's used as interjection. And in this phrase it's used as a command to fire. So, basically, "Огонь по готовности" translates 1 to 1 into "Fire at will". (Both Russian and English phrases are kinda idiomatic, so those two carry exact same meaning both being idioms in English and Russian)
//Sorry for slight off-topic