# Do Overwatch characters say different things when they cast their ultimate?

Tags: overwatch

This is for Mei

Dòng zhù! Bùxǔ zǒu! (self and hostile)

Freeze! Don't move! (friendly)

What actually happened?

Mei just screamed a sentence and all her foes will listen to Dòng zhù! Bùxǔ zǒu! and her friends will listen Freeze! Don't move!

Or Mei shout two sentences. One to her friends' headsets and the other to his foes headsets?

What actually happened?

Or it's just a game mechanic. The foes listen to hostile?

Realistically I see no reason why a character would bother "warning" their opponents before killing them. But how is this actually done in game.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266926/what-are-all-the-friendly-and-enemy-ultimate-sounds

Comment: Mei is a woman...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mention, there are two voice lines for each ultimate (a [list](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266926/what-are-all-the-friendly-and-enemy-ultimate-sounds) is available).
Each time an ultimate is used, the player who activates it AND the enemy team hear Version A (*Dòng zhù! Bùxǔ zǒu!*), while their team members will hear Version B (*Freeze! Don't move!*)

This is done so players can react instantly. Just by memorizing the two different voice lines for each hero, you can easily tell what ultimate ability is activated and if you need to run or attack.

Comment: and in general, foreign(non english) = enemy ult, english = friendly ult

Comment: Well, more precisely, enemy ultimate callouts are always loud, and sometimes in that hero's native language (with several exceptions). Friendly ultimate callouts are quieter, and always in English. Generally these are different callouts, but sometimes (maybe just Reinhardt Winston and Roadhog) not.

Comment: Should probably link to the answer Dragonrage linked in a comment on the question. That lists all the different quotes.

Comment: Good idea, and done :)